# Temperature based graph OR custom color for each and every point?

Tags: javascript, python, ios, graph, temperature

Directly we go to explanation.

**What I have:**

1. Content1(Mobile_Company - name based on a model): LG, Moto, Apple,
   etc.,
2. Content2(Location):County1, Country2, Country3, etc.,
3. Content3(Average_Mobile_expected_temperature - normal temperature at morning_time):
   28, 27, 26, etc.,
4. Content4(Mobile_actual_temperature - at morning_time): (Country1: 28, 28, 25,
   etc.,), (Country2: NA, 30, 26,
   etc.,), (Country3: 25, 28, 35,
   etc.,)
5. Content5(Date_and_time): morning_time, afternoon_time,
   evening_time

Based on this I need to show graph like (Handmade drawing)
[image]

1. Green - Maintaining correct temperature value
2. Red - Temperature value variation
3. Black - Temperature value not available

When tap tool tip shows correspond temperature value

Is there any tool to generate a graph like this?
I am going to work `Objective-C`, If it's available other languages I am Ok with `Swift`, `JavaScript` and `Python`. Apart from this also ok (Just want to if available or not)

Comment: This question is way too broad when you start specifying several languages, I'd suggest just looking at existing charting/graphing libraries for your language.

Comment: I tried `Objective C`, I couldn't find anything like what I expect. So, I plan to show this content via `WebView` they why other options.

Comment: For Javascript I know there are some libraries like D3.js and Chart.js so you could start looking at those. But I'd stick to languages you're strong at already.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.